# Search an array for a key and output the value

Tags: php, arrays

I have a large array in PHP that has this snippet of data. Is there a way to search through an array and find the value of "date" without traversing through all the nodes?

It should be noted that "date" in itself isn't unique but `$subscription->schedule_next_payment->date` is.

```
[schedule_next_payment] => WC_DateTime Object

(
    [utc_offset:protected] => 0
    [date] => 2021-01-29 14:26:43.000000
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => Europe/London
)
```

Comment: If I understood correctly, you have a large array of subscriptions and are looking to extract the date value from a specific subscription?

Comment: @El_Vanja Within each subscription array there's a tonne of other data but I just specifically want the date from each one.

Comment: _"without traversing through all the nodes"_ - Unless you use the date as a key, then you'll have to do some looping.

Comment: "...the date from *each one*" - that's a dead giveaway of an inevitable loop. Even if you did it with PHP's built-in functions, they'd still internally loop the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the array is sorted by date, you could perform a [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).

If not, I'm afraid you need to either change the way you get the data (like changing database systems) or somehow handle having to loop through all that.